# Only allow ProxyPass for some IP's

Tags: apache-2.2, reverse-proxy

With the following snippet, everyone can access both /foo and /bar

```
ProxyPass /foo http://example.com/foo
ProxyPassReverse /foo http://example.com/foo 
ProxyPass /bar http://example.com/bar
ProxyPassReverse /bar http://example.com/bar
```

But what if I want /foo to be accessible for everyone, and /bar only for requests coming from a specific IP, is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can use a `SetEnvIf` directive checking the Remote Address (`Remote_Addr`).

With one IP:

```
SetEnvIf Remote_Addr "123.123.123.123" TRUST=yes
```

Checking multiple IPs with regular expression

```
SetEnvIf Remote_Addr "123\.123\.123\.123|134\.134\.(134\.(134|134)|134\.134)" TRUST=yes
```

I'm not sure you can do directly this:

```
ProxyPass /foo http://example.com/foo env=TRUST
```

But probably you can work with Rewrite Rules and obtain the same result...

For example you can rewrite to a particular page all the IP that are not trusted (`env=!TRUST`)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Passing env=TRUST gives a syntax error, but your second suggestion put me in the right direction. Adding a rewriterule BEFORE any proxy definitions in httpd.conf worked. See detailed instructions on this site: http://www.the-art-of-web.com/system/rewrite/#section_1

Answer (score 5):

The answer should be as follows. I have included an IP and a subnet in one rule, for those who need to allow a whole subnet rather than a set of single IPs.

```
<Location /foo>
    Deny from all                       // **This rule is the most IMPORTANT**    
    Allow from 192.168.1.2 10.100       // The second value implies 10.100.0.0/16 subnet
    ProxyPass http://example.com/foo
    ProxyPassReverse http://example.com/foo
</Location>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
<Location /bar>
    Allow from 1.2.3.4 2.3.4.5 ...
    ProxyPass http://example.com/bar
    ProxyPassReverse http://example.com/bar
</Location>
```

Note the first argument to ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse is implied here to be the target of the location block.